# Consuming _error queue in masstransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

For each queue masstransit has consumers, it automatically creates a `[queuename]_error` queue, and moves messages that could not be processed there (after retrials, etc.)

I´m trying to create a consumer, that takes errors from that queue, and writes it to a database.

In order to consume those messages, I had to create a handler/consumer for the error queue, receiving the original message.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "myqueuename", e =>
{
    e.Handler<MyMessage>(ctx => 
    {
        throw new Exception ("Not expected");
    });
});

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "myqueuename_error", e =>
{
    e.BindMessageExchanges = false;
    e.Handler<MyMessage>(ctx =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handled");
        // do whatever
        return ctx.CompleteTask;
    });
});
```

All that works fine, the problem to retrieve the actual exception that occurred.
I was actually able to do that, with some serious hack....

```
e.Handler<MyMessage>(m =>
{
    var buffer = m.ReceiveContext.TransportHeaders
                    .GetAll().Single(s => s.Key == "MT-Fault-Message").Value as byte[];
    var errorText = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(buffer)).ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine($"Handled, Error={errorText}");
    return m.CompleteTask;
});
```

That just fells wrong though.

PS: I Know i could subscribe to a `Fault` event, but in this particular case, it is a `RequestClient` (request-response) pattern, and MT redirects FaultAddress back to the client, and I can´t garantee it is still running.

Comment: Request/reply should only be used for getting the data. It means that if the requestor goes down - there are no more reasons to reply with data or with fault and you do not have interest in consuming faults.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev That comment just there is gold. Made me realize a lot of problems I´ve been having are coming from that misunderstanding. If you post that comment as answer I´ll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request/reply should only be used for getting the data. It means that if the requestor goes down - there are no more reasons to reply with data or with fault and you do not have interest in consuming faults.

So, the reason for the request client to use a temporary (non-durable) queue instead of the receive endpoint queue is by design. It encourages you not to understand that the scope of your replies is only within the request waiting time.

If you send commands and need to be informed if the command has been processed - you should publish events to inform about the outcome of the command processing. Using message metadata (initiator id and conversation id) allows you to find out, how events correlate with commands.

So, only use request/reply for requesting information (queries) using [decoupled invocation SOA pattern](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/decoupled-invocation/), where the reply only have a meaning in correlation with request and if the requestor goes down, the reply is no longer needed, no matter if it was a success of failure.